# Idiom to describe an insensitive comment

Tags: idiom-requests

I saw an idiom used on Twitter a while back, but I don't remember what it was.

It was used in the context of someone making an unfunny joke about a sensitive topic such as Auschwitz. It was used like

> That joke is very ______.

It may have started with "out of ____", but I'm not sure.

Is there any idiom that you can think of?

Edit: It had a nuance of questioning the common sense of the person who made the comment. It may have been “out of touch”. Would that idiom make sense in this context?

Comment: It was a bit harsher, more like questioning the person’s character. “out of bounds” and “out of place” both sounds like they’re disapproving the action but not the person. Please see my edit.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the phrases such as "out of touch", "out of bounds", to see if they mean what you think they do; or looking them up in a thesaurus. There are a lot of idioms that more or less fit, but it's hard to find the specific one you want.

Comment: "tasteless" or "in poor taste" were the first two idioms that came to mind when reading your title/example sentence - "That joke is very *tasteless* / That joke is *in very poor/bad taste*"

Comment: Maybe better to use a more specific term - racist, sexist, ageist, antisemitic, ableist,..., based on what makes it out of line. Just saying that a joke is inappropriate doesn't really send a helpful message as to what makes it so.

Comment: Tactless, untactful, boorish, clumsy, inconsiderate, discourteous, rude, indiscreet, undiplomatic, abrupt, bad-mannered, uncouth, insolent, ungracious,............

Answer (score 31, accepted):

***Out of line***

> beyond what is considered acceptable behavior:
>
> - You can disagree with her, but calling her dishonest was out of line. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-line))

It is quite common to describe comments as *out of line* nowadays. It means unacceptable (because it is insensitive).

Comment: This is very common within meme material [[ https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/hes-out-of-line-but-hes-right ]] though the usage is not restricted to meme world !

Comment: Not that in idiomatic usage of "out of line" one would probably say "That joke is _way_ out of line" rather than "that joke is _very_ out of line".

Answer (score 22):

In colloquial British usage, *out of order* is sometimes used in this way. Sometimes intensified to *right out of order*.

It refers to any unacceptable behaviour, not only speaking insensitively.

Comment: (+1) As a common Britishism, I would also suggest another intensifier, *[bang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bang#Adverb) out of order*

Comment: Reminds me of that film with Simon Pegg where he walks around the pub with a sign saying ''Out of order'' around his neck which he took from a toilet door.

Answer (score 15):

Another expression that could be used is 'That joke was **beyond the pale**'.

> *beyond the pale* [phrase of *pale*]
>
> outside the bounds of acceptable behaviour
>
> - "The language my father used was beyond the pale."

[[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=beyond+the+pale&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=beyond+the+pale&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i433i512j0i512l3j46i175i199i512j0i512l4.4127974353j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

The [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beyond_the_pale) definition shows that the expression conveys disapproval of the person (if any) being described:

> **beyond the pale** [idiomatic]
>
> Of a person or their behaviour: outside the bounds of what
> is acceptable

Comment: Which is itself a bit of an insensitive double entendre given the starting point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_of_Settlement Although the idiom probably stems from the Irish Pale. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pale

Answer (score 9):

A relatively new term would be **[tone deaf](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tone-deaf)**.

Originally directly connected to music, where the listener is incapable of recognising musical pitches, it has come to mean a failure to recognise socio-political issues.

<sup>Though I agree if it starts 'out of…' then 'line' (US) or 'order' (UK) would be most appropriate.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

> That joke is very off-colour

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-colour) dictionary:

> 3. GRADED ADJECTIVE.
>    An off-colour joke or remark is rather rude or offensive.
>    *He denies making off-colour remarks about women.*

You could even say simply:

> That joke was slightly off.

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off) dictionary

> 22. GRADED ADJECTIVE [v-link adv ADJ].
>     If you say that someone's behaviour is a bit off, you mean that you find it unacceptable or wrong.
>     [informal]
>     *Some of the dialogue is slightly off.*

Comment: Generally 'off-color' (at least in Am. English) refers to something that is rude, offensive, or inappropriate specifically because of its sexual nature, which doesn't fit OP's use.  Compare 'working blue'.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for ***out of pocket***, which, in slang, means something that was uncalled for and/or inappropriate.

[The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/interactive/2022/gen-z-work-slang-quiz/) describes it as "suggesting something is inappropriate or wild."

The same term is described by [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_pocket) as shocking/unexpected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've only ever heard this phrase refer to money that you have to pay yourself, like the portion of a doctor's bill not covered by insurance.

Comment: I’ve added links to 2 slang definitions. There’s also a Reddit thread on this term: https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/15e938w/what_does_out_of_pocket_mean/

Comment: This usage is pretty obscure, and easily overshadowed by the "had to pay for it yourself" meaning.

Comment: Nonetheless, it could well be the example they saw, considering it was on Twitter, which is very likely to use slang.

Comment: This is a complete misinterpretation of that quiz from the Washington Post. "suggesting something is inappropriate or wild." - no, the phrase is being used to suggest "I'm going to use money flippantly" and the consequences follow. It's suggesting "I'm going to spend unlimited money at the bar/brothel/other to go wild". It is not an phrase for insensitive comments.

Comment: @roganjosh What? How did you reach that conclusion? The correct answer the quiz gives is exactly what Washingtonian1 said.  The phrase has absolutely nothing to do with money in this context. Look at the top result for "out of pocket" on urbandictionary (maybe not if you're at work) if you want more evidence.

Comment: Despite the other commenters on this answer not being familiar with terms from AAVE that have been more widely adopted as slang among the youth (go figure), "out of pocket" is almost synonymous with "out of line" in that context though usually more humorous than admonishing. If you've received any downvotes for this they reflect the ignorance of those casting them rather than anything else.

Comment: @Washingtonian1- Mos def. Could be useful for understanding what was said, just wanted to add my vote to the "it's rather niche slang" idea.

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike among people <25 years old, I think that the obscure meaning is actually the "pay for it yourself" meaning, and everyone would instead recognise the "outrageous" meaning at first

Comment: @theonlygusti - Totally possible. Thanks for the perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> *[What you just said was]* [***below the belt***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+below+the+belt)
> Unfairly targeted at one's weakness or vulnerability. The phrase refers to boxing, in which hitting an opponent below the waist is prohibited.
> *I know she really wants the promotion, but telling the boss about my personal problems was below the belt.*

Note that you wouldn't normally use this idiom if someone made an ***insensitive / distasteful*** comment about something like the Holocaust, because that's a context where millions (if not *billions*) might take offense (it's normally used in the context of *personal* attacks).

Answer (score 1):

"Out of touch" would make sense in that scenario, but joking about Auschwitz is deplorable so it's likely that (since this is Twitter) the person said "out of pocket" which basically means "you went too far" or "why you would say something like that". *Very* common to hear that idiom used among younger people in America nowadays. "Out of line" has a very similar meaning to this.

Out of touch is usually reserved for people doing/saying something that *used* to be acceptable or commonplace for the scenario. Out of pocket / out of line is generally used for people doing/saying something that was *never* acceptable / commonplace for the scenario.

To those saying that "Out of pocket"  is used for paying cash up-front instead of a loan or something similar, yes, of course it is. The two meanings aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).